# LINQ left join with count - multiple table joins Visual Studio 2015 MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating a production dashboard to shows the number of widgets produced by each work center in intervals of one hour.  There are 'trigger' and 'target' values for widget production over the course of each hour.  My query works...however it doesn't show a particular interval hour if no widgets were produced in that hour.  I'm trying to do a sort of left outer join on the interval target table to capture all possible intervals but haven't been able to show intervals that have a zero widget count.

```
dbvm.widgetSummary = from wc in db.workCenters
                  from w in db.widgets.Where(w => w.createdByID == wc.ID && w.packDate >= beginDate && w.packDate <= endDate)
                  from d in db.departments.Where(d => d.ID == wc.deptID && wc.display == true)
                  from g in db.goals.Where(g => g.workCenterID == wc.ID && g.hour == w.packDate.Value.Hour)
                  group g by new { wc.ID, wc.friendlyName, g.hour, g.trigger, g.target, d.dept } into n
                  select new WidgetSummary()
                  {
                      createdByID = n.Key.ID,
                      friendlyName = n.Key.friendlyName,
                      hour = n.Key.hour,
                      actualWidgets = n.Count(),
                      triggerWidgets = n.Key.trigger,
                      targetWidgets = n.Key.target,
                      variance = (n.Count() - n.Key.target),
                      dept = n.Key.dept

                  };

return View(dbvm);
```

Comment: With a query this complicated, I'd advocate for using straight sql rather than trying to do EF or Linq-To-SQL.

Comment: These look like inner joins to me. I usually see `DefaultIfEmpty` when they are left joins

Comment: Thanks - I have tried several combinations of DefaultIfEmpty() but none of the versions that I yielded the desired results.

Comment: Rework your query.  You want all workCenters, all goals, all departments, and (some) widgets.  Put widgets at the end as a left join (DefaultIfEmpty).

Comment: Thanks - I did see where I was restricting my goals by widgets...I reworked it and now get expected results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do a [left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins).

```
from wc in db.workCenters
join jw in  db.widgets.Where(w => w.packDate >= beginDate && w.packDate <= endDate) on wc.ID  equals  jw.createdByID into wgj
from w in wgj.DefaultIfEmpty() ...
```

But why don't you have `wc.Widgets` and `wc.Departments` and `wc.Goals`. Seams to me your domain model is not all that Object oriented and you are just using flat tables without relationships.
Also if you are using EF you might want to look in to [perf optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#4)